# Setting environment variables of mkl

Tags: sh, intel-mkl

In order to set the environment variables of the mkl toolset on linux, I have to execute the script `mklvars.sh`. But now I get the errors

```
/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: 33: /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: typeset: not found
/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: 34: /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: typeset: not found
/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: 36: /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: typeset: not found
/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: 37: /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: typeset: not found
/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: 38: /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: typeset: not found
/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: 39: /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: typeset: not found
/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: 40: /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: typeset: not found
/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: 41: /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: typeset: not found
/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: 42: /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: typeset: not found
/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: 43: /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: typeset: not found
/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: 44: /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: typeset: not found
/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: 45: /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: typeset: not found
/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: 46: /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: typeset: not found
/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: 82: /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: typeset: not found
/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: 83: /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: typeset: not found
/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: 84: /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: typeset: not found
/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: 87: /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: typeset: not found
/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: 90: /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: typeset: not found
/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: 91: /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: typeset: not found
/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: 92: /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh: typeset: not found
```

The error lines start with

```
typeset SCRIPT_NAME=$0
typeset MOD_NAME=mod

typeset MKL_LP64_ILP64=
typeset MKL_MOD=
typeset MKL_TARGET_ARCH=
typeset MKLVARS_VERBOSE=
typeset MKL_MIC_ARCH=
typeset MKL_BAD_SWITCH=
typeset OLD_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
typeset OLD_LIBRARY_PATH=
typeset OLD_MIC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
typeset OLD_NLSPATH=
```

How can I fix that, and what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

`source /opt/intel/<address>/mklvars.sh`

For example, I remember I did,

```
source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64
```

You need to source the environment variables. This should solve your problem. Hope it works !

Comment: Hmm, nevertheless that does not add the path variables, but at least I can execute it, thanks!

Comment: Why does sourcing work and not just running the shell script? What's happening behind the scenes?

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe Just running the shell script spawns a subprocess to run the script, and any changes in the environment variables are contained in that subprocess (and its own subprocesses, if exported). Whereas sourcing the script affects the current process running the shell.